# Filter a list of strings using a pair of strings

Tags: string, list, haskell, functional-programming, tuples

I want to define a Haskell function that removes from a list of strings any string contained in a pair of strings and returns only a list that contains all the remaining strings. So an example would be:

```
function ["football","basketball","soccer"] ("football", "basketball") = ["soccer"]
```

I know you can use the `filter` function to filter list that satisfy the predicate given. I know that I can filter out a list in this manner:

```
function' xs s = filter (/=s) xs
```

But I can't figure out how to get this to work with tuples. I keep getting errors when I run the code. Any idea how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfunc :: Eq a => [a] -> (a, a) -> [a]
myfunc xs (a,b) = filter (\x -> (x /= a) && (x /= b)) xs
```

Lets see type of `filter`

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

When you do `filter f xs`, 
it just applies the function `f` of type `a -> Bool` on all the elements of the list removing those for which this function returns `False`.

I have pattern matched on elements of the tuple as `(a,b)` and I just defined function `f` as `\x -> (x /= a) && (x /= b)`. This is an anonymous function which takes an element of the list and returns `True` only when it is neither equal to first element of the tuple nor equal to the second element. `&&` is boolean `and` so it returns `True` only when both its arguments are `True`.

Comment: could you explain this a little further. I want to ensure that I'm understanding this correctly. Thanks

Comment: @Bobo I have added the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution would use a list of strings to filter instead of just a pair.  An even more general solution would use a list of anything that supports `Eq` instead of just strings.

So, we're looking for something with type:

```
Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

A quick search on hoogle yields `(\\)`

```
import Data.List ((\\))

main = print $ ["football","basketball","soccer"] \\ ["football", "basketball"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward method would be to run your filter twice, like so.

```
tupleFilter :: (Eq a) => [a] -> (a, a) -> [a]
tupleFilter xs (a, b) = function' (function' xs a) b
```

The key here though is that you pattern match on (or otherwise deconstruct) your tuple before using the elements in a filter.

Here's a version without your intermediate filter function, which should be probably be inlined in this case for future readability.

```
tupleFilter xs (a, b) = filter (\x -> (x /= a) && (x /= b)) xs
```